# Define a Method inside Adapter and call from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I defined a method inside a RecyclerView adapter and want to call it from MainActivity but I can't. Please guide me.

**My MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, GetDataAdapter1, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

            int firstVisible = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisible = manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.i("TAG", "onScrolled: " + firstVisible);
            Log.i("TAG", "Last Index: " + lastVisible);
            recyclerViewadapter.changeItem(firstVisible,lastVisible);
        }
    });
```

**My Adapter**

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter.size();
}

public void changeItem(int position){
    firstVisible = position;
    notifyItemChanged(firstVisible);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView IdTextView;
    public TextView NameTextView;
    public TextView PhoneNumberTextView;
    public TextView SubjectTextView;
```

This changeItem I want to call from MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

you declared the function with one parameter:

```
public void changeItem(int position)
```

but you call it with 2 parameters:

```
recyclerViewadapter.changeItem(firstVisible,lastVisible);
```

also I'm pretty sure that in these lines:

```
firstVisible = position;
notifyItemChanged(firstVisible);
```

`firstVisible` will not be in scope. You should read up on how parameters and scoping work.

Comment: HI @Grisu,, If I am givinf adapter.MethodName  in my MainActivity then its should be show me option to create a method inside Adaper.. but I am unable to create.

Comment: Okay.. A little help i need. I  am using ScrollListener in MainActivity. so I want to call a methos which Have first visibl Item and last visible ite,  How can I define it in Adapter and able to access inside MainActivyt

Comment: just define it with 2 parameters in the adapter: `method(int param1, int param2)`